# Nested array upto n child, set it for options

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm developing a category module by using laravel as backend and Vue.js as frontend.

I've used this library [Laravel Nestable](https://github.com/atayahmet/laravel-nestable)

And its giving the desired output.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Category One",
    "slug": "category-one",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Category Two",
        "slug": "category-two",
        "child": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Category three",
            "slug": "category-three",
            "child": [],
            "parent_id": 2
          }
        ],
        "parent_id": 1
      }
    ],
    "parent_id": null
  }
]
```

But the problem is how can I use this nested array upto N depth for the options in vue. For example:

```
<option value="1">Category One</option>
<option value="2">-Category Two</option>
<option value="3">--Category Three</option>
<option value="4">---Category Four</option>
<option value="5">Category Five</option>
```

And the above desired output can not be achieved by this

```
<option v-for="category in categories" value="category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
```

So if you have any solution or suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: Did you try me answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `parent_id` in data for adding `-` as:

```
<option v-for="category in categories" value="category.id"><span v-if="category.parent_id">{{getDash(parent_id)}}</span>{{category.name}}</option>

new Vue({
    ...
    computed: {
        getDash: function (parentId) {
          let string = '';
          for(let i = 0; i < parentId; i++) {
            string += '-'
          }
          return string;
        }
    }
    ...
})
```

Comment: It will not work out and the above solution can just add the - on the child.

Comment: That's what you wanted in desired output, no?

Comment: do you want to display tree structure? If yes, you will have to use something else rather than select may be using ul & li that will loo like select

Comment: The json shown in above code block is the one which I'm getting through the API, its the nested. But the issue is how to process this nested json into the select so that, if we receive the json upto the Nth child then select will show the parent and its child hierarchy.